# Make Faye working with SSL and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, https, ssl-certificate, faye

I'm developing a chat-based app with Ruby on Rails.
Since I have to make the app show the messages in realtime, I decided to implement pub/sub with the gem "render_sync".
That gem is using Faye as server to handle push notifications.

So I configured everything like here's explained (https://github.com/chrismccord/render_sync), started the main server at port 3000, the faye server at port 9292, and it works seamlessly.

But when I decided to move my app under SSL (with a self signed certificate), it is not working anymore.

I created a self-signed certificate for the main server and a configuration file:

**server.yml**

```
port: 3000
ssl: true
ssl_key_file: server.key
ssl_cert_file: server.crt
```

then I started the main server with the command:

```
> thin -C config/server.yml start
```

At this point the app is working under SSL, but the push notifications don't.
So - looking at the chapter *Serving Faye over HTTPS (with Thin)* from the link posted above -, I edited "server" and "adapter_javascript_url" fields in **sync.yml** file, and I tried to create a configuration file for the Faye server like this:

**sync_thin.yml**

```
port: 4443
ssl: true
ssl_key_file: faye.key
ssl_cert_file: faye.crt
environment: production
rackup: sync.ru
```

but I can't figure out what should I put in *ssl_key_file* and *ssl_cert_file* fields!

Should I put the same .key and .crt files generated for the main server? Or do I must generate another couple of key e cert?
I tried to generate another couple of those, but the browser warns me saying that the cert is invalid.

Can anyone help me, or show me an example of a working faye ssl server somewhere?